# Compiling Qt - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, compilation

**I am looking for any tutorials or information on compiling Qt 4.7 with Visual Studio 2010.**

I've recently have run into an bug using Qt 4.7.1 libraries on Visual Studio 2010 and have found information that recompiling Qt with 2010 can potentially solve it. ***Edit***: This has solved the issue.

Ref: http://www.qtforum.org/article/34406/heap-corruption-caused-by-calling-selectedindexes-method-of-qitemselectionmodel-class.html

After Researching for awhile, I was successfully able to compile Qt in VS2010 using the following:

**Compile:**

1. set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2010
2. configure -platform win32-msvc2010
3. nmake

**Integration to VS2010:**

1. Download Visual Studio Qt add-in and install
2. Select from menu: Qt/Configure Qt Versions.
3. Add new version to point to compiled binaries
4. Restart Visual studio and rebuild
   projects.

Hope this helps others...

**Further Refs:**

http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/ 
http://blog.paulnettleship.com/2010/11/11/troubleshooting-visual-studio-2010-and-qt-4-7-integration/
http://dcsoft.wordpress.com/2010/01/30/how-to-setup-qt-4-5-visual-studio-integration/

*Note: recompiling for VS2010 fixed bug experienced above.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like [this](http://psi-im.org/wiki/Compiling_Qt4_on_Windows#Compiling_Qt4_using_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B.2B_.28unsupported.29)?

[Here](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/compiler-notes.html#visual-studio-windows) is the [official](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/install-win.html) documentation.

Comment: For reference - a working step-by-step guide is posted as an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010/5791452#5791452

Answer (score 3):

I've used jom instead of nmake for faster compilation. Here is my step-by-step compilation guide: http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/

Answer (score 1):

Qt V4.8.0 contains prebuilt binaries for Visual Studio 2010 so you don't need to build manually anymore:
http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2010

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the QMAKESPEC if you are passing -platform win32-msvc2010 to configure

define the QTDIR environment variable to poitn to the 4.7.1 top level dir. Less stuff requires it now with the improved vs integration but it makes setting paths easier, especially if you use multiple versions.

Comment: I received a few errors when configuring without setting it. It would say it couldn't find "QMAKESPEC(win32-msvc)".