# Some of QT examples are not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt4

After building QT via my Visual Studio 2010 as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010) I find out that most part of demos doesn't work. When I open qtdemo.exe and try to `Launch` some of them (for example `Demonstrations->Browser`, `Demonstrations->Media Player`, `Qt Declarative Examples->TV Tennis`, ...) the same error message `"Could not launch the example. Ensure that it has been built."` I get.

Comment: The error message is probably accurate. You might not have built the examples you're trying to launch. By their names I guess they are probably depending on Phonon being built. So you might have to configure Qt to include Phonon. 

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/configure-options.html

It's a guess, so I didn't add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you followed these configure flags from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010), then obviously not all examples will work. These are the ones for a minimalistic Qt build:

```
configure.exe -release -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-qt3support -no-multimedia -no-ltcg
```

If you want all example to work (except webkit), then use this:

```
configure.exe -release -no-webkit -no-ltcg
```

If you want the to build everything (takes something like 17 GB of HDD space and half a day):

```
configure.exe
```