# Fail to compile QT 4.7.3 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt4.7

After following guide on how to compile QT with Visual Studio 2010 I still havent managed to make it work.

I get the following error during the "configure" process.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcpmt.lib'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x450'
```

I mainly followed something like this:

[How to build Qt for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you

- Open a Visual Studio command prompt, or run vcvars32.bat to set up Visual Studio's environment vars properly
- Extend the PATH variable to include $(QTDIR)\bin, where $(QTDIR) is where you installed Qt
- Just for comparison, here's my configure string: configure -debug-and-release -opensource -shared -ltcg -no-accessibility -no-qt3support
- Then you can run nmake and go to dinner.

Comment: Thank you it works with your configure command... I don't know why but it works.

Answer (score 1):

It should be part of the standard install, check "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib"

If that's ok then check your paths are set in the wherever you are starting qmake from, are you using the VS tools command prompt?

Comment: Yes the file is in the lib folder...

And yes it is from the VS tools command prompt