# NMAKE : fatal error U1077: return code '0xc0000135'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, nmake

I'm trying to follow steps explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010): but after entering the following into console:

```
configure.exe -release -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-qt3support -no-multimedia -no-ltcg
```

I'm getting following error:

```
....  
....  
....  
Running syncqt...  
Creating qmake...  

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -c -Fo./  -W3 -nologo -O2  /MP  -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators\unix -Igenerators\win32 -Igenerators\mac -Igenerators\symbian
 -IE:\qt_source\include -IE:\qt_source\include\QtCore  -IE:\qt_source\include -IE:\qt_source\include\QtCore  -IE:\qt_source\src\corelib
\global  -IE:\qt_source\src\corelib\xml  -IE:\qt_source\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010   -IE:\qt_source\tools\shared  -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO
_UNICODETABLES -DQT_LITE_COMPONENT -DQT_NODLL -DQT_NO_STL  -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -DUNICODE -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_NO_THREA
D  -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED  -DQLIBRARYINFO_EPOCROOT -c -Yc -Fpqmake_pch.
pch -TP qmake_pch.h
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0xc0000135'
Stop.

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        del qbitarray.obj  qbuffer.obj  qcryptographichash.obj  qfsfileengine.obj  qfsfileengine_iterator.obj  qbytearray.obj  qvsnprin
tf.obj  qbytearraymatcher.obj  qdatetime.obj  qdir.obj  qdiriterator.obj  qfile.obj  qtemporaryfile.obj  qabstractfileengine.obj  qfsfi
leengine_win.obj  qsystemlibrary.obj  qfsfileengine_iterator_win.obj  qfileinfo.obj  qglobal.obj  qhash.obj  qiodevice.obj  qlist.obj
qlinkedlist.obj  qlocale.obj  qmalloc.obj  qmap.obj  qregexp.obj  qtextcodec.obj  qutfcodec.obj  qstring.obj  qstringlist.obj  qtextstr
eam.obj  qdatastream.obj  quuid.obj  qvector.obj  qsettings.obj  qlibraryinfo.obj  qvariant.obj  qurl.obj  qsettings_win.obj  qmetatype
.obj  qxmlstream.obj  qxmlutils.obj  qnumeric.obj
Could Not Find E:\qt_source\qmake\qbitarray.obj
        del project.obj main.obj makefile.obj unixmake.obj unixmake2.obj mingw_make.obj  option.obj winmakefile.obj projectgenerator.ob
j property.obj meta.obj  makefiledeps.obj metamakefile.obj xmloutput.obj pbuilder_pbx.obj  borland_bmake.obj msvc_nmake.obj msvc_vcproj
.obj msvc_vcxproj.obj  msvc_objectmodel.obj msbuild_objectmodel.obj symmake.obj initprojectdeploy_symbian.obj  symmake_abld.obj symmake
_sbsv2.obj symbiancommon.obj registry.obj epocroot.obj
Could Not Find E:\qt_source\qmake\project.obj
        del qmake_pch.obj
Could Not Find E:\qt_source\qmake\qmake_pch.obj
        del qmake_pch.pch
Could Not Find E:\qt_source\qmake\qmake_pch.pch
        del qsystemlibrary.obj
Could Not Find E:\qt_source\qmake\qsystemlibrary.obj
        del vc60.pdb
Could Not Find E:\qt_source\qmake\vc60.pdb
        del vc70.pdb
Could Not Find E:\qt_source\qmake\vc70.pdb
        del qmake.pdb
Could Not Find E:\qt_source\qmake\qmake.pdb
        del qmake.ilk
Could Not Find E:\qt_source\qmake\qmake.ilk
        del qmake.tds
Could Not Find E:\qt_source\qmake\qmake.tds

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -c -Fo./  -W3 -nologo -O2  /MP  -I. -Igenerators -Igenerators\unix -Igenerators\win32 -Igenerators\mac -Igenerators\symbian
 -IE:\qt_source\include -IE:\qt_source\include\QtCore  -IE:\qt_source\include -IE:\qt_source\include\QtCore  -IE:\qt_source\src\corelib
\global  -IE:\qt_source\src\corelib\xml  -IE:\qt_source\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010   -IE:\qt_source\tools\shared  -DQT_NO_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO
_UNICODETABLES -DQT_LITE_COMPONENT -DQT_NODLL -DQT_NO_STL  -DQT_NO_COMPRESS -DUNICODE -DHAVE_QCONFIG_CPP -DQT_BUILD_QMAKE -DQT_NO_THREA
D  -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_PCRE -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED  -DQLIBRARYINFO_EPOCROOT -c -Yc -Fpqmake_pch.
pch -TP qmake_pch.h
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0xc0000135'
Stop.
Building qmake failed, return code 2


E:\qt_source>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A web search for "return code 0xc0000135" turned up the information that this means nmake cannot find the compiler. Which means that you did not start nmake in a Visual Studio command shell. If you want to use a standard command shell you have to call vcvarsall.bat or similar in the VC directory of you Visual Studio installation. If it still does not work, check the INCLUDE and LIB environment variables. They should contain ...\VC\INCLUDE and %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include and the corresponding LIB dirs.

Comment: And your Qt tree really is in "e:\Qt_source" and your Visual Studio is in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0" and you have sufficient rights to read those directories?

Comment: I'm getting 'the program can't start because mspdb100.dll is missing from your computer' message.

Comment: Now when I've added this mspdb100.dll to the directory where cl.exe is, I'm getting following error: e:\qt\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/global/qglobal.h(45) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or
directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
Building qmake failed, return code 2

Comment: It looks like you Visual Studio Installation is broken or incomplete. You should try to re-install/repair it and install all features.

Comment: @smallB let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1259/discussion-between-hmuelner-and-smallb)

Comment: this whole configure process works now. But unfortunately I'm having problem after running nmake. Something with incompatible manager or something similar. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

when you configured you forgot to add the comipiler option..

Open up microsoft visual studio command prompt and navigate to the directory of Qt source code.

type

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2010
```

and then run

```
nmake
```