# Building LIBSVM on WIndows

Tags: libsvm

I am trying to do a build from the command line for a windows PC of the version of LIBSVM 3.17 modified to allow weighted instances 
(from http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/#weights_for_data_instances ). 
I am using the executable tools from Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, but am getting an error I don't understand. Microsoft's documentation of the error gets me no further. Can anyone point me in a useful direction, or has anyone managed to compile this package for Windows?

I am running at the command line:

```
nmake -f Makefile.win
```

and getting an error:

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0     \VC\bin\cl.exe"' : return code '0xc0000135' Stop.

The full makefile is:

**CXX = cl.exe
CFLAGS = -nologo -O2 -EHsc -I. -D __WIN32__ -D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
TARGET = windows

all: $(TARGET)\svm-train.exe $(TARGET)\svm-predict.exe $(TARGET)\svm-scale.exe     $(TARGET)\svm-toy.exe lib

$(TARGET)\svm-predict.exe: svm.h svm-predict.c svm.obj
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-predict.c svm.obj -Fe$(TARGET)\svm-predict.exe

$(TARGET)\svm-train.exe: svm.h svm-train.c svm.obj
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-train.c svm.obj -Fe$(TARGET)\svm-train.exe

$(TARGET)\svm-scale.exe: svm.h svm-scale.c
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-scale.c -Fe$(TARGET)\svm-scale.exe

$(TARGET)\svm-toy.exe: svm.h svm.obj svm-toy\windows\svm-toy.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) svm-toy\windows\svm-toy.cpp svm.obj user32.lib gdi32.lib comdlg32.lib      -Fe$(TARGET)\svm-toy.exe

svm.obj: svm.cpp svm.h
$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c svm.cpp

lib: svm.cpp svm.h svm.def
$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -LD svm.cpp -Fe$(TARGET)\libsvm -link -DEF:svm.def 

clean:
-erase /Q *.obj $(TARGET)\**
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to compile it from visual studio directly since is easier, but if you still want to do it from the command like this link might help:

[NMAKE : fatal error U1077: return code '0xc0000135'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622869/problem-with-nmake)

Apparently the problem is that NMake couldn't find the compiler's path.

Comment: No, that wasn't it: see below.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered (by guessing) that I needed to manually create a directory called "windows" where the executables were produced. Not entirely sure why this was necessary, but it did the job, and I still can't see a way to do it without doing so.