# Building PBRT v2 error - Error 1 error U1077: 'if' : return code '0x1'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, nmake, pbrt

I have visual studio 2013 community edition and I got the pbrt-v2 code base and have been trying to build the solution but this is one of the errors I have been getting (it is related to nmake it seems like):

```
 NMAKE - Error  1 error U1077: 'if' : return code '0x1'
```

I am not sure what to do as other instructions does not seem to be very clear. Any help would be greatly  appreciated! Thank you and have a great day!

-------------- UPDATE --------------------

I got it to compile and build on visual studio 2013. The problem was that I think I had outdated files for PBRT. Basically what I did was I checked out the project via github, which I believe should work but then I noticed you can download the latest pbrt-v2 files on the website. In fact the authors has a solution file for VS studio 2015, which I deleted and reinstalled 2013 since I thought that was the problem. Regardless, using the 2012 from the file I downloaded straight from the website I was able to build the solution. I'll keep the question up just in case anyone has a similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error code relates to NMAKE getting an error from a command.  However [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622869/nmake-fatal-error-u1077-return-code-0xc0000135) previous suggests that it may also happen if your Visual Studio installation is incomplete or has become corrupt or that NMAKE was not run in a VS command shell.  Suggest you look at that question and consider some it's possibilities.

Have you tried the MSDN forum ?

Comment: Thanks stephen, can you tell me how to check if nmake runs in a VS command line or not before I rule out vs studio being corrupt.

Comment: You should be able to open a console window from the VS menus, maybe under tools - don't have a VS version to hand.  Run `nmake` from there.

Comment: Alright I will try that out, I am not around a computer at the moment but as soon as I am will get your suggestion.

Comment: If you look at my update I got it to build, even though I did not have to invoke your suggestion. You did try and your solution might be useful so I accepted the answer.