# Resolving LNK4272 errors

Tags: compiler-errors, lnk2019, nmake, lnk2001

i have a problem with Pgvector extension installation on Windows

so the code for installation is

```
set "PGROOT=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15"
git clone --branch v0.4.2 https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector.git
cd pgvector
nmake /F Makefile.win
nmake /F Makefile.win install
```

and i am getting fatal error:

C:\Program Files\pgvector>nmake /F Makefile.win

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\lib\postgres.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
vector.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 109 unresolved externals

and i get bunch of LNK 2001 & 2019 errors apart from these.

i'm using;
MSVC v143 package
Windows universal CRT SDK
Windows 10 SDK

Answer (score 2):

I'm not expert in compiling at all but I manage to do it. Here is how I did it:

- firstly you can't run nmake directly from the command prompt tool: [NMAKE : fatal error U1077: return code '0xc0000135'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622869/nmake-fatal-error-u1077-return-code-0xc0000135) :

  > [...] "Which means that you did not start nmake in a Visual Studio command shell. If you want to use a standard command shell you have to call vcvarsall.bat or similar in the VC directory of you Visual Studio installation"

How I compiled the extension:

- download Visual studio community 2022 and install ALL component related to windows and C++ (I say ALL to not being bother with missing lib but if you lack of space you could cherry pick the lib to install)
- find where is the vcvarsall.bat file (usually: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build)
- download the pgvector extension from github and place it in a easily callable folder like: c:/pgvector
- find the root folder of your postgresql installation (like: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15)
- identify the CPU you are using because you will need to choose a parameter later:

  vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
  vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64 10.0.10240.0
  vcvarsall.bat x86_arm uwp 10.0.10240.0
  vcvarsall.bat x86_arm onecore 10.0.10240.0 -vcvars_ver=14.0
  vcvarsall.bat x64 8.1
  vcvarsall.bat x64 store 8.1
- you are now ready !
- find in the windows bar the following tool: Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022
- type the following commands (adapt it if needed):

  ```
  cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build
  vcvarsall.bat x64
  set "PGROOT=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15"
  cd c:/pgvector
  nmake /F Makefile.win
  nmake /F Makefile.win install
  ```

It works for me on two computers, hope it will work for you as well or could help other users in the future.

Comment: In Windows you have to execute cmd as administrator for "nmake /F Makefile.win install", like sudo. Works for me.