# Integrating Qt Framework, Netbeans IDE, Visual Studio C++ Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, netbeans

I'm using *Qt 4.7.4 as C++ framework*, *Netbeans 7.0 as IDE* and *MinGW as C++ compiler*.

These are integrated well due to Netbeans ability and I'm coding my projects with them easily.

I know in Qt Creator, we can switch to Visual Studio as C++ compiler very easy.

But, **how can we use Visual Studio as C++ compiler in Netbeans which works with Qt framework?**

Is there any Netbeans plugin or some configuration for it (then, Only F6 to run)?

*Note: As mentioned in comments (Cat Plus Plus), it's related to `QMAKESPEC` or `-spec`. and i'm searching for a solution via `Project > Properties > Qt > ...`*

Comment: If the integration means it's using `qmake`, then it's a matter of choosing another makespec (via -spec or QMAKESPEC environment variable).

Comment: As Cat says, qmake is the way to go.  I would point out that you don't want to compile with Visual Studio, it's Visual Studio's C++ compiler which you're after ([see this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw(v=VS.100).aspx) for options available)

Answer (score 1):

You might try using `qmake -spec win32-msvcXXXX` where XXXX is from {2003, 2005, 2008, 2010} and matches your version of Visual Studio.

I would, however, expect that you will have to rebuild Qt for Visual Studio.  The MingW libraries will not work with Visual Studio.  The answers to [How to Build Qt for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010) may help here.  [I freely admit to never trying this.]