# Building Qt for VS2010 with nmake returns link error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, nmake

I'm trying to build Qt for visual studio 2010 and I'm following the instruction in the accepted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010)

I'm using the modified configure command:

```
configure.exe -release -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-qt3support -no-multimedia -qt-libpng -qt-zlib -qt-libmng -qt-libtiff -qt-libjpeg
```

Which works fine, but when I start the nmake it eventually fails and returns me this error:

```
itemviews\qabstractitemview.cpp(2311) : error C2039: 'Key_BackSpace' : is not a member of 'Qt'
itemviews\qabstractitemview.cpp(2311) : error C2065: 'Key_BackSpace' : undeclared identifier
itemviews\qabstractitemview.cpp(2311) : error C2051: case expression not constant

...

Generating Code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

The original command I was using was the one used in the post mentionned earlier but I added these:

```
-qt-libpng -qt-zlib -qt-libmng -qt-libtiff -qt-libjpeg
```

and removed this:

```
-no-ltcg
```

for it to work properly, but the nmake still won't work.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: No platform specification in the configure command? Maybe that's not necessary when using configure.exe, though, I'm not sure. [Here](http://eecs.vanderbilt.edu/research/hmtl/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=Knowledge.Qt) is the way Qt is built from source for VS 2008 and 2010 in my lab. We have no problems. Perhaps you can compare notes on that install process and see where your problem lies.

Comment: Exact same error here with Qt 4.6.4, with VS2008 in 64bits, doing a simple: configure -release -static -fast -no-qt3support -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-dbus -no-openssl -platform win32-msvc2008  
followed by nmake. I think Qt 4.8.2 had the same issue, but I don't remember well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely way after the fact here, but I was able to work around this issue by commenting out the Qt::Key_BackSpace case in qabstractitemview.cpp on line 2311 for QT 4.6.4. I guess the key definition was changed in a patch or something equally goofy. You can find the file in /%My QT Directory%/src/gui/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Or you could try to take this error from another perspective, like the typo or something else. In fact, this problem *is* kind of errors with typo. Try to modify the original `Qt::Key_BackSpace` to `Qt::Key_Backspace`, and `nmake` again. I have encountered the very problem you post here and I **do have used the *comment-out* way**. Until I occasionally took a look at my keyboard just under the screen..., yeah, it is *Backspace* rather than *BackSpace*!

Besides, to be more concrete, you may checkout the snippets in the same source files in the following versions, like:

Qt 4.7.4: %QTDIR%/src/gui/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp(2321): `Qt::Key_Backspace`

Qt 4.8.1: %QTDIR%/src/gui/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp(2337): `Qt::Key_Backspace`

Comment: This actually fixes the problem, thanks! And it's obviously much cleaner than commenting out the case. It should be the accepted answer :).

Comment: Thanks..fixing the typo save my day :)