# Qt SDK 1.2.1 -- cannot find nmake

Tags: c++, qt, nmake

**EDIT: It seems I can use the nmake from \Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe, but it would be nice (and much more user-friendly) if the "Qt 4.8.1 for Desktop" took care of this automatically.**

I installed Qt SDK under Windows 7, 64 bit, using the online installer. I used the default installation options.

Now I am trying to build the Notepad app under **\QtSDK\Examples\4.7\tutorials\gettingStarted\gsQt**. I am using the supplied "Qt 4.8.1 for Desktop" command line.

For the first two steps of the build, **qmake** runs perfectly, but then **nmake** cannot be found in my installation. It's not a problem of setting a path -- I cannot find nmake.exe (or anything resembling nmake) anywhere in the QtSDK folder and subfolders.

If I use **make** or **mingw32-make**, I get the famous missing separator error:

```
c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Workspace/qt_notepad'
Makefile.Debug:59: *** missing separator.  Stop.
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Workspace/qt_notepad'
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
```

Is this a buggy installation, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nmake is release with MSVC toolchain. Hence, you can not find it in the QtSDK.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010) is for you reference.

Comment: So even if I don't want to use Visual Studio, I need to compile it for usage under Windows? I think it might be easier to just use it under Linux, then...thanks for the pointer, nevertheless!

Comment: No you do not need nmake to build Qt applications on windows. I would download the package that includes QtCreator. That should contain a working mingw compiler and have no dependency on Microsoft compilers or toolchains.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm sure the QtCreator solution is working, but, for various reasons, I would prefer to manually build my projects in the command line...is this at all possible without compiling Qt from source?

Comment: Are you sure QtSDK is installed with qtcreator? If you just want to build your own project, you don't need to build QtSDK from source. What you shall do is just to link it, no matter you work in command line environment or IDE.

Comment: @liuyi I downloaded the Qt SDK, which is supposed to contain everything. Perhaps I misunderstood, but I thought if I build in the command line supplied with this installation, the paths would be already set such that qmake and nmake work out of the box. But apparently they are not!

Comment: Can you build your own project in qtcreator? If your answer is no, I am afraid Qt libraries are not installed. The most directly way is to search Qt libraries in your install path.

Comment: Yes, I can build it. The only issue I had: to build manually I need nmake, and I need to run it in the VS command line, as it doesn't work in the shell supplied with Qt (as I would have expected).

Comment: Open `Microsoft Visual Studio Command Prompt` from your `Start Menu`, then nmake is available. I want to know what happens when you execute command `qmake && nmake`. Please give more information about your problem. The exact error message will help a lot more.