# Qt5 libs compiled with vc110 for vs2012?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012

I wanted to ask, are there qt5 pre-compiled versions for Visual Studio 2012. The add-in runs fine with me, but I can not start the program, because the appropriate *.libs missing.

Has someone happened to be there a compiled version to download or a configuration to translate the sources?

greetz, Tobias.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build Qt for Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: No, there is not pre-compiled qt5 for Visual Studio 2012. You have to compile it on your own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find some already compiled vs2012 Qt5 libraries [in here](http://releases.qt-project.org/digia/5.0.2/).
But those are for x64 platform only...

(for example http://releases.qt-project.org/digia/5.0.2/latest_successful/qt-windows-opensource-5.0.2-msvc2012_64-x64-offline-2013-03-14-456.exe)

For x86 you will need to compile Qt by yourself, and that's a bit of pain (especially if you need WebKit included) + takes really long compilation time.

When compiling you can try and follow this:
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

Plus, found some interesting russian guy blog site that may be worth checking out: http://habrahabr.ru/post/168671/

Comment: Just found some interesting tool called "BlueGo" (that can be found here http://vertexwahn.de/) Didn't tested it yet, but looks like it should make a life a bit easier when compiling Qt5 (and other popular libraries like boost for example..) on VS2012, just check it out ;)