# OpenCV C++ interface and Qt framework

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, interface, crash

I've been using OpenCV to create a project I need to make. I made a fully functioning console application, and now want to make it more graphical (adding a GUI). I'm using Qt for that.

Everything went well, I was getting into Qt programming, but then something strange happened. When I was calling some of my functions from the Qt project, I was experiencing strange crashes. From some reason, certain opencv functions fail when called from a 'qt project'. Functions include split, findChessboardcorners, cornerSubPix, ...

Does anybody has ANY idea why this might happen? I'm using OpenCV 2.4.2, and Qt 4.8.4. I'm using the C++ interface for opencv.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm using Windows 7, 64 bit. IDE is Visual Studio 2010.

Kind regards,
Philip

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same configuration as you but my project is a MakeFile Project.

As project property for NMAKE :

Build Commande Line :

```
$(QTDIR)\bin\qmake
```

Rebuild All command line :

```
$(QTDIR)\bin\qmake -project
nmake debug-clean
nmake debug
```

Clean Command Line :

```
$(QTDIR)\bin\qmake
nmake debug-clean
```

Be sure to use Qt and OpenCV in same format. I compiled both in x64 with the OpenCV compile tutorial and this one for Qt : [How to build Qt for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I did build Qt from the source files (did not use prebuilt libraries). All the examples work, so Qt is not the problem, I guess? (correct me if I'm wrong).

However, I am using OpenCV prebuilt binaries. Should I rebuild everything using the instruction from http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide ? I've read somewhore that I should specifically build OpenCV with the Qt flag set, and by using the MinGW compiler?

Comment: No, you don't necessarily need to build OpenCV. I make it work on another PC with the prebuilt. Have you create a .pro file and include the lib you need ? LIBS += -LPathToLib\ -lopencv_calib3d242d (Don't specify the .lib) ? But what bother me it's the fact some function work and other don't.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's what I think is strange as well. Everything should be linked fine, since I can work with opencv functions (like loading images, converting color spaces, etc...). What I did notice though, is that for example, the C interface function (cvFindChessboardCorners) does work... So that's even stranger, no?

Comment: I have nothing to say except try to post here : http://answers.opencv.org/questions/

Comment: Okey, I'll try there. Thanks for your input.