# Release Qt program. Dependencies trouble

Tags: c++, qt, dependencies

I have the application .exe and the requested Qt .dll files in the same folder. I have also created the folder "platforms" and put qwindows.dll in there.

The program starts, but no nothing is shown on the screen, just white.

I don't know how to debug this.

I tried Dependency Walker, but I don't know/understand how to use the information the tool provides me. This is the output when I load my .exe file with Dependency Walker:

[image]

Comment: are they the only dependency issues you have? the ones showing in the image I mean.  Also what version of QT are you using and what compiler/ide name and version?

Comment: There are a lot more dependencies, but there are the ones that seems to give errors/warnings. Using Qt 5.1.1 MSVC2010 with Qt Creator

Comment: Copying `libEGL.dll` from Qt will resolve the `GPSVC.dll` and `IESHIMS.dll` dependency issue (has for me in the past).  However you will encounter issues with qt 5.0.1 and GCC 4.7, as they are incompatible.  Qt 4.8 is however compatible with GCC 4.4, and QT 5.2 is compatible with GCC 4.8.0, either of which will ensure a more trouble-free compilation:)

Comment: you may have to incorporate the msvc2010 c++ distributable package from [32 bit download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5555) or [64 bit download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=14632) before your app can run independently

Comment: @GMasucci: I have the libEFL.dll already. Also the 32 and 64 bit of msvc2010 c++ is installed on the computer running it.

Comment: There is a nice walkthrough of how to distribute Qt exes at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html  along with lists of dll files and where to find them, as well as using static linking to reduce the number of dlls you need to redistribute with your exe.

Answer (score 2):

Copying `libEGL.dll` from Qt should resolve the `GPSVC.dll` and `IESHIMS.dll` dependency issue (has for me in the past). However you will encounter issues with qt 5.0.1 and GCC 4.7, as they are incompatible. Qt 4.8 is however compatible with GCC 4.4, and QT 5.2 is compatible with GCC 4.8.0, either of which will ensure a more trouble-free compilation:)

You may have to incorporate the msvc2010 c++ distributable package from [32 bit download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5555) or [64 bit download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=14632) before your app can run independently

Also, for release version of QT apps you may well have to build your own QT from source, as the distributed version only used to include support for debug mode (as discussed [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010)

There are also some trouble-shooting guides at [paulnettleship.com](http://blog.paulnettleship.com/2010/11/11/troubleshooting-visual-studio-2010-and-qt-4-7-integration/) which, whilst they require some changes to point to the right directories for more modern versions than Qt 4.7, are still nice, short useful reference guides.

Another good guide to compiling your own Qt (VS again)is located [here](http://briolidz.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/compiling-qt-with-visual-studio-2010/), whilst there is a Qt MinGW guide [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MinGW)  which gives a walkthrough of how to compile Qt Desktop using minGW.  There is another (in my opinion) more straightforward guide at [http://wiki.batcom-it.net/](http://wiki.batcom-it.net/index.php?title=Building_Qt_on_Windows_%28MinGW%29) which walks through the actual build steps and is quite reasonably updated.

Comment: Nice answer, but can you please add references for MinGW compiler as well?